# CSS Animation isn't hidden at beginning

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to have a div, with a word inside.  This word should appear with animation when the div is hovered over. This is animating and behaving the way I want, EXCEPT... the word "hello" is visible when the page loads.  I want it to be hidden, and then animate into view.  What do I need to fix?

```css
#test{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
#hello {
    animation-name: hello;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
#hello:hover {
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-play-state: running;
    visibility: visible;
}

@keyframes hello {
    0%      {visibility:(hidden);transform:scale(0.5); opacity:(0.0);}
    1%      {visibility:(visible);}
    50%     {transform:scale(1.2); opacity:(0.5);}
    100%    {transform:scale(1.0); opacity:(1.0);}
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="hello">
    Hello!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using non-animatable properties (`visibility`) is bad practice, use `opacity` for the purpose intead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply remove `()` from the values of properties as it make them invalid. Also it's better to change the opacity in the 1% of the animation to be able to see the scale effect.

*You may also remove the `visiblity` property from the CSS as it's useless since you are using opacity*

```css
#test {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background:#fff;
  overflow:hidden; /* added this to avoid the scroll to appear and disappear*/
}

#hello {
  animation-name: hello;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#test:hover #hello {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-play-state: running;
  /*visibility: visible; can be removed*/
} 

@keyframes hello {
  0% {
    /*visibility: hidden; can be removed*/
    transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    /*visibility: visible; can be removed*/
    opacity:0.3;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    opacity:0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity:1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="hello">
    Hello!
  </div>
</div>
```